# Cómo acceder a la API de buenosaires.gob.ar con usuario y contraseña

Tags: reactjs, api, react-native

Tal vez sea muy simple, pero llevo días sin dar con la solución. 
Estoy intentando acceder a una API desde `https://apitransporte.buenosaires.gob.ar/console/`
allí me interesa la de colectivos. Con usuario y pass consigo la API que uso en la aplicación, pero no funciona, no devuelve resultados.
Uso react y el código con el que intento acceder es el siguiente, (por las dudas no copié toda la API completa). Muchas gracias

```html
import React from 'react'
import Bus from './Bus'

class BusContainer extends React.Component{
    constructor (props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            buses: []
        }
    }
    
    componentDidMount (){       
          fetch('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://apitransporte.buenosaires.gob.ar/colectivos/feed-gtfs?client_id=.....&client_secret=........')
           .then(response => response.json())
          .then(busesJson => this.setState({buses : busesJson}))
        
    }

    // componentDidUpdate (){

    // }

    render(){        
        return <Bus name="asd"/>
    }
}
export default BusContainer
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola antes de hacer la petición en código te sugiero pruebes con algún cliente REST, por ejemplo POSTMAN. si te regresa información ya procedes con código, te invito a leer este articulo, [https://es.reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html][1].

```
 componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://apitransporte.buenosaires.gob.ar/colectivos/feed-gtfs?client_id=myid&client_secret=mykey")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            items: result.items
          });
        },
        // Note: it's important to handle errors here
        // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
        // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
        }
      )
  }

  [1]: https://es.reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me fue de gran ayuda!